# Prompting users to fill multiple lines of data within the textbox-ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, textbox

I want to know whether its is possible to fill multiple lines within the single textbox.
For ex. I have a textbox where the users have to fill various details like,

Asset Model:

Asset Make:

Version:

Sl.No:

within the single textbox and also is it possible to check whether the user filled the textbox using RequiredFieldValidator?
Here is the code i used for now,

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDes" runat="server" Height="100px" Rows="8" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: What do you mean by that  `fill multiple questions`? You can concatenate strings and set text of multiplelines of TextBox. Like :  `string line1 = "line1";
                string line2 = "line2";
                txtDes.Text = (line1 + Environment.NewLine + line2);`

Comment: Hi, i meant to say multiple lines. I have resolved the issue. Thanks